# Convert dictionary comprehension to python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

**Input:** we have a dictionary in this form with a lot more data

```
d = {
ag : ID name num 
0  id1  a  10
1  id2  s   7
2  id3  d   2,

rp : ID name num 
0  id4  f  13
1  id1  n  11
2  id8  p   4
}
```

**Output:** I want to get all this into single dataframe

```
   ID name num 
0  id1  a  10
1  id2  s   7
2  id3  d   2 
3  id4  f  13
4  id1  n  11
5  id8  p   4
```

**Code:** I tried this but didn't get the desired output

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.items()}).reset_index()
df.columns = ['ID', 'name','num']
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(d.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

```
>>> df
    ID name  num
0  id1    a   10
1  id2    s    7
2  id3    d    2
3  id4    f   13
4  id1    n   11
5  id8    p    4
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it. I dont want to concat

Comment: Why 'concat' is a problem? Do you have some trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
ag : ID name num 
0  id1  a  10
1  id2  s   7
2  id3  d   2,

rp : ID name num 
0  id4  f  13
1  id1  n  11
2  id8  p   4
}

df = pd.concat(d.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

The dataframes you want to concatenate are the values of your dictionary, so you can just pass `d.values()` directly to `pd.concat()`.